# regexp which allows free text and html tags

Tags: html, regex

I need some help in order to create a regular expression which allows me to insert free text and nested html tags.

This is an example of what I mean:
the regexp will validate this text

```
Free text <a href="http://www.mysite.com">this is a <b>test</b></a>
```

and

```
Free text <a href="http://www.mysite.com">this is a test</a>
```

but it won't validate this (because the tag "a" isn't closed)

```
Free text <a href="http://www.mysite.com">this is a <b>test</b>
```

Is someone able to help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't the right tool for this job: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: This is literally impossible to do with regexps.

Comment: @Town:so do you mean that it's impossibile to make this check via regexp but I need a server/client side validation in order to check if each opening tag has a corresponding closing tag?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? Is this an editor for people to input links and format text?  If so, why not give them a WYSIWYG editor instead so they don't have to worry about the HTML?

Comment: @Town: the idea is only to check if any html tag has the corresponding closing. I think that you imagine that I'm working on a back-end website which allow the User to arrange the contents of a front-end website. Moreover the User will be able to insert <a>, <b>, <i>, <u> and <img> tag. I'also have a particular user control which allow the user to enter contents in multilanguage, so a FCKEditor is a little bit more!

Answer (score 0):

If the full extent of the input is what you've listed above, you can use the following:

```
<a[^>]+>.*?</a>
```

If it's a ton of code, you could create 2x regexes:

```
<a[^>]+> 
</a>
```

and compare the total number of matches for each.